# Java VM version is invalid (TestNG)

Tags: java, testng

I am working on an old java project that's still using Java 1.6 . I need to write some test suites for this project and wish to use TestNG for this purpose. However, on running the test I continuously get the error

```
VM version 1.6.0 is invalid, Java 1.7 or above is required for running TestNG.
```

I checked out the other similar questions but none of them answer my query. Downloading an old version of TestNG also doesn't work (I tried several 6.8.22 versions). I am using a mac.

Can someone please help me with this? Is it possible for me to define a different execution environment for testNG only? (so that the rest of the project runs Java 1.6 but testNG takes 1.8)

Any kind of help will be great. Thanks

Comment: Only testng 6.9.4 and above need at least java 7. How do you run TestNG? With Eclipse?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33475970/error-while-running-testng-test